# Is 'implicit sharing' heritable from Qt classes?

Tags: c++, qt, copy-on-write, qshareddata

If I create a subclass of an implicitly shared Qt class (e.g., QList), will my subclass be implicitly shared as well?

I read the [brief introduction to implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html#implicit-sharing-in-detail) located in the QtCore5.3 documentation, but I didn't see any mention of heritability.

My purpose in asking is to try to write more efficient code when deciding which arguments to pass and how to pass them.

Comment: Please be aware that QList does not have a virtual destructor and thus should not be used as a (public) base-class. It is very easy to run into UB problems if you do.

Comment: In such cases it is prefferable to use aggregation instead of interheriance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, the Qt classes using *implicit-sharing* are usually data-containers or tools and are not intended to be subclassed.
You can notice that because there is no virtual destructor, actually no virtual function at all.

Because of the risks and bad practice, you probably want to make a different design without inheritance.

---

To answer your question :

How *implicit-sharing* works ?
The class instances share the data and explicitly tell when they need to modify this data (and thus, deep-copy it) by calling a `detach()` function.
So the motherclass data would still be a shared data-pointer, and the motherclass methods would still detach at appropriate time. **But** your subclass data members would **not** be implicitly-shared and your subclass methods would **not** implicitly detach when it might be needed.
You might also overload methods and forget to detach, and so mess up the shared data.

You do **not** benefit of the implicit sharing, you have to explicitly set it again for your own data.
You will need to encapsulate the data in a shared-data container, and manage the `detach` in your methods. Check the doc :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html#details